# it seems too many emulator instances are running on this machine. Aborting

Tags: android

When I run it from the SDK manager, the loading process works, but once it is done, a flash of the emulator appears then quickly disappears.

Sometimes after it loads, nothing happens.

At the worst when it loads, I get the "too many emulator instances are running on this machine. Aborting" message.

I want to start making apps, but this seems to be the only thing stopping me!
I had already turned off Windows Firewall.
pl'z, give me solution 
Eclipse Indigo; r12, Windows 7 (64)

Comment: create an AVD with minimum RAM.

Answer (score 6):

The Android emulator uses loopback ports (5554, 5556, etc) to communicate with the external ADB. If it can't do so, it assumes that other emulator instances are occupying these ports.

Failure to do so can be because:

A) Your ports are occupied? Try netstat -an | grep 5554

B) Your loopback interface is not configured - You said you're on Windows - Make sure Windows Loopback is configured (try pinging yourself). (On Linux the same would be achieved by "ifconfig lo", and see. It should be configured, with the right IP (127.0.0.1) and up.

Incidentally, it's MUCH easier to use Android SDK on Linux, because that way both target and host are Linux. Consider running the whole thing in a VM image - and your SDK Experience will be immeasurably easier. From experience.

Answer (score 4):

I also had an error problem  `ERROR   | It seems too many emulator instances are running on this machine. Aborting.` in the emulator windows command.

I had a lot of virtual networks, all of which were active, because of the `VirtualBox` and `vmware` installation.

**Solution:** Disabling all those networks solved my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason is that I was using wsl-based docker on Windows.

1. Try disabling the option `Use the WSL based engine` in the docker settings (which resorts to using Hyper-V)
2. Enable Hyper-V in Windows Features.
3. Restart your computer and you should see it work like a charm.
4. My virtualbox VM, android emulator and docker now works together!

---

Answer (score 0):

I have Hyper-V enabled (Intel CPU) for use with Docker and WSL2, on Windows 10 21H1.

Returning to Android programming after a hiatus, I reinstalled Android Studio today (4.2). It tried and failed to install HAXM (which is not surprising as it won't work with Hyper-V). I then was unable to open Android virtual devices.

After hunting around for answers (mostly people saying to disable Hyper-V which I was not ready to give up on), I found the exact process command line for the emulator and ran it in an admin window for good measure. Enter the "it seems too many emulator instances are running on this machine" error, previously invisible, which led me here. I checked ports and shouted into the void - nothing helped.

**Then I rebooted**, on the off chance something in all those attempts was somehow still holding resources (despite killing every related process).

**The Android virtual device worked after that reboot, with Hyper-V still active.**  I hadn't changed anything that should have required a reboot, but evidently some resource(s) were locked along the way in my previous session.

(Also note that if you don't touch/edit `\qemu.conf` on whatever drive you run from (typically `C:`) you will see the incorrect `Your emulator is out of date` error if running from the command line.)

Answer (score 0):

Just enable Hyper-V from Windows features

Comment: And how does that solve the problem asked by OP?

Answer (score 0):

A simple restart fixed this issue for me.